# Display a fail alert when using "PUT" with xmlhttp

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am currently writing stuff back to the database using :

```
xmlhttp.open("PUT","...",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml");
xmlhttp.send((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation")[i]));
```

I want a alert if this fails, for example the database does not support PUT or something like that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start [reading more about XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest)

To check for errors, you can bind a function to the error event:

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener('error', errorCallback);
```

This callback will be fired if any error occurs during the execution of the request (a server error, a connection error, and so on).